# How to two strings in #define?

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

I'm using

```
#define SITO @"http://localhost:3000"
#define MISSING @"http://localhost:3000/photos/large/missing.png"
```

Is it possible to do this dynamically? I mean

```
#define SITO @"http://localhost:3000"
#define MISSING @"<<SITO>>/photos/large/missing.png"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use...

```
#define MISSING SITO @"/photos/large/missing.png"
```

Comment: It works. Just keep in mind that you end up with @"http://..." @"/photos"; it's more or less concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed you embed one micro within other. But you could nested as suggested by @Simon Lee.

Use the below approach.

```
#define SITO @"http://localhost:3000"
#define MISSING @"<<%@>>/photos/large/missing.png"
```

Construct a string as belwo.

```
NSString* Missing = [NSString stringWithFormat:MISSING,SITO];
NSLog(@"Missing %@", Missing);
```

Comment: Actually you can nest defines as per my answer. :)